# CSS - absolute within fixed with overflow for scrolling and 100% height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have a scrollable overlay of some sort that blanks out the rest of the site.
I can't seem to get 100% height on the absolute element within my fixed element.

http://codepen.io/intellix/pen/GBltK

```
section {
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  overflow-x:auto;

}

article {
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  width:300px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

If I set bottom: 0; on the absolute element, it fills height when the page doesn't overflow. When the page overflows it leaves a gap.

When I use bottom: auto on my absolute element it fills height with overflow, but leaves a gap without overflow!

If you resize the window so the content fits and then resize so the content doesn't, you can see that it doesn't work in both cases.

Comment: Nevermind my previous comment, it was incorrect.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you want to use min-height and bottom:auto here.

```
article {
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  width: 300px;
  bottom: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

The reason you need `min-height:100%;` and can't use `height:100%;` is because when the `section` content in scrollable it's height is actually **greater** than 100%.

Longer explination:

With positioned (`position: relative|fixed|absolute;`) elements, percentage based heights are determined relative to their offset parents.  In the case of the `article` element, it's offset parent is the `section` element.

The `section` element uses `top:0px;` and `bottom:0px;` to determine it's height.  These values are determined by the height of it's offset parent which is the `html` element

`html` is a special case where `height:100%;` is the size of the view-able window, which is why your scrollable element has a height larger than 100%.

Comment: thanks so much, works. Now I have no idea why min-height is required instead of height, if you know why?

Comment: I added a long winded explanation to the answer :-)